# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'text.txt' in fs (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am getting error when trying to read a file 'text.txt' using readFileSync()

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const text = fs.readFileSync("text.txt", "utf-8");
console.log(text);
```

Getting

I also tried changing name of the txt file but nothing happened

Comment: Is there a `test.txt` in the working directory of your program? The working directory might not be the program's directory.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The file does not exists. What does your folder structure looks like, what is your cwd?

Comment: Hey this may happen if you are running this program from another directory in the terminal. Make sure you're issuing the cmd: node your-file-name from the file's directory. Also try using a relative path e.g., "./test.txt" .